# Pre Calculate Date in Oracle SQL Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sql query which looks like this

```
select 
*
from TABLE@REMOTE
where 1=1
and (NODE = 3521 or node = 3787) 
and TIME_START > sysdate - 1
and TIME_END < sysdate + 1;
```

Works super fast.
Now I have the adjust the `time_start` and `time_end` a litte bit:

```
select 
*
from TABLE@REMOTE
where 1=1
and (NODE = 3521 or node = 3787) 
and TIME_START > CONVERTtoTimeZone(sysdate - 1, 'UTC')
and TIME_END <CONVERTtoTimeZone(sysdate + 1, 'UTC')
```

Now the query is getting really slow. Is there a way to pre calculate the `time_start` and `time_end` in advance?

Comment: What is the data type of `time_start` and `time_end`?

Comment: the datatype is `DATE`

Comment: `CONVERTTOTIMEZONE()` appears to be a home-made function. What is it doing?

Comment: Basically this: `select CAST(FROM_TZ(CAST(P_DATE AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE) into d from dual`

Comment: Please show us the execution plan. Your function `CONVERTtoTimeZone` should have no influence on performance.

Comment: Any change when you use conversion directly, i.e. `TIME_START > CAST(FROM_TZ(CAST(sysdate - 1 AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE)` or maybe better `TIME_START > CAST((SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' DAY) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE)`

Answer (score 3):

Define `CONVERTTOTIMEZONE()` as a `DETERMINISTIC`.  Like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CONVERTTOTIMEZONE (x_date DATE) 
  RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC IS...
```

Without being defined as deterministic, Oracle does not know that your function will return the same output for the same input every time.  So, it must evaluate your function for each row instead of just running it once at the beginning.  That's a waste of time in itself, but it also prevents the use of any indexes.

NOTE: the function really needs to *be* deterministic or else you'll get wrong results.  Based on your comments, your function is deterministic though.

For more information on `DETERMINISTIC`, see the latest database documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/DETERMINISTIC-clause.htm#LNPLS-GUID-6AECC957-27CC-4334-9F43-0FBE88F92654

Comment: And avoid useless `select ... into ... from dual;`. Just write `RETURN CAST(FROM_TZ(CAST(P_DATE AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE);` inside your function.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit True enough, but I doubt that's the cause of any performance issues.  Beginning in Oracle 10.1, the Oracle optimizer replaces access to the `DUAL` table with `FAST DUAL`, which does not even do a logical I/O.  It will do this as long as you are not actually selecting or using the `DUAL.DUMMY` column.

Comment: I tried co rewrite the function, however I can't compile and don't find the problem. Do I still need the select into? `create or replace FUNCTION CONVERTTOTIMEZONE  (P_DATE IN DATE ) 
RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC IS CAST(FROM_TZ(CAST(P_DATE AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin' AS DATE);
END CONVERTTOTIMEZONE ;`

Comment: still no success `create or replace FUNCTION CONVERTTOTIMEZONE (P_DATE IN DATE ) 
RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC IS RETURN CAST(FROM_TZ(CAST(P_DATE AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin' AS DATE);
END CONVERTTOTIMEZONE;`

Comment: You're missing the BEGIN statement between the `IS` and the `RETURN CAST...`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to save the value before run your query:

```
WITH timeTable AS (
select CONVERTtoTimeZone(sysdate - 1, 'UTC') as dayBefore, CONVERTtoTimeZone(sysdate + 1, 'UTC') as dayAfter
from dual)
select 
*
from TABLE@REMOTE
where (NODE = 3521 or node = 3787) 
and TIME_START > (select dayBefore from timeTable)
and TIME_END < (select dayAfter from timeTable)
```

Ps. I removed `1=1` :)

Comment: I did try that, however no success